# How to apply gradient using svg filter

Tags: svg, gradient, svg-filters

I want to create a filter that when applied to an html element, would apply a gradient to the entire element. The css gradient only applies to the background, so it is not what I want.
What I want is say my element contains a triangle and a circle, I want to apply a filter to my element and the triangle and the circle would have a gradient applied to them.

This is what I've got so far:

```css
.my-element{
    filter: url(svg.svg#filter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="lightGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(-5)">
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5" offset="5%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0.2" offset="6%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0.3" offset="19%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0.2" offset="12%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.8" offset="13%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.9" offset="15%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="15%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="16%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.8" offset="16%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.9" offset="18%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="18%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="20%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" offset="20%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" offset="25%"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <rect id="recGradient" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#lightGradient)"/>

        <filter id="filter" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feImage x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="#recGradient"/>

            <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Edit: with the above code the element just becomes invisible in Firefox, in chrome it seems to work.

so, obviously I'm doing it wrong. I have no idea how to create svg filters, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try creating a rect with a gradient and then pointing an feImage filter at the rect.

Comment: @robert hi, can you show me an example code? I tried add `<feImage xlink:href="#recGradient"/>`, but it gives parse error: prefix not bound to a namespace

Comment: @RobertLongson ok I added xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", now it parses, but I'm not getting the result I want. I will edit the post to show what I did.

Comment: The rect element should be outside the filter.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, I put it outside of `<filter>` but still it's invisible.

Comment: fiterUnits is a typo. Not sure if Chrome supports external filters, Firefox does support external filters but only supports feImage pointing to complete files and not fragments.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, i fixed the typo, but still nothing. I'm giving up because the support seems to be poor, and it's not worth it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you construct a cross-browser filter that does what you want here. The sizings are tricky because you're defining a rect with an applied gradient within a DataURI, then pulling that into a filter using an feImage and then applying that to HTML content using the SVG filter trapdoor in CSS filters. But it does work.

(BTW - it's not clear whether you want to retain the color of the original text and just apply a opacity gradient, or whether you want the black/white gradient to over-ride the original color. You can toggle this by changing the "in2" to "in" in the feComposite. This governs whether you're applying the opacity of the sourcegraphic to the gradient or vice versa.)

```css
div {
  filter: url(#myGradient);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
<filter id="myGradient" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200px%22%20height%3D%22200px%22%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient%20id%3D'lightGradient'%20gradientTransform%3D'rotate(-5)'%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.4'%20offset%3D'0%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.5'%20offset%3D'5%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'black'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.2'%20offset%3D'6%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'black'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.3'%20offset%3D'19%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'black'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.2'%20offset%3D'12%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.8'%20offset%3D'13%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.9'%20offset%3D'15%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0'%20offset%3D'15%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0'%20offset%3D'16%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.8'%20offset%3D'16%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0.9'%20offset%3D'18%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0'%20offset%3D'18%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'0'%20offset%3D'20%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'1'%20offset%3D'20%25'%2F%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'white'%20stop-opacity%3D'1'%20offset%3D'25%25'%2F%3E%3C%2FlinearGradient%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20id%3D'recGradient'%20x%3D'0%25'%20y%3D'0%25'%20width%3D'100%25'%20height%3D'100%25'%20fill%3D'url(%23lightGradient)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
 </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>




<div>
  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text   Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text    Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text    Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text    Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text    Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text    Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text  Imagine a very large piece of text   
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using firefox, and i don't see any thing when running the code snippet...

Comment: uuuh. something's screwy with my data URI, let me debug

Comment: Sorry - firefox wants URL encoded UTF-8 - should have known this. Updated example - works now.

Comment: thank you. It is working. But it seems that this filter changes the color and opacity of the text? I want the text to be the same, and just paint the gradient on top of the text. So, a 40% opacity red would just be the solid text with 40% opacity red painted on it. Maybe I should use operator="arithmetic"? I'm completely clueless, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Just change to operator="over". (But not to criticize, but this seems a bad use of filters. Why don't you just draw a shape with a gradient on top of the other elements directly using positioning, z-index and CSS gradient fills?)

Comment: what do you mean by css gradient fills? are you talking about background: linear-gradient()? My shape is animated (rotation animated), but I want my gradient to stay static, I want it to apply to the shape but not rotate with it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks for the use case!